# How can I calculate the derivative of an integral with respect to a parameter if Leibniz's formula gives a divergent integral?

Tags: integration, integral-transforms, resolution-of-singularities, numerical-integration

We are working on the problem related to a magnetic field in an axially symmetric magnetic plasma trap. Let's express the vector potential through the magnetic flux function

\begin{gather}
\label{1:01}
A_{\theta } = \left\{0,\frac{\psi (R,Z)}{R},0\right\}
.
\end{gather}

The magnetic field vector is expressed in terms of magnetic flux:

\begin{gather}
\label{1:02}
\vec{B}(r,z)
=
\left\{-\frac{\psi ^{(0,1)}(R,Z)}{R},0,\frac{\psi ^{(1,0)}(R,Z)}{R}\right\}
.
\end{gather}

Now let's introduce the Green's function
\begin{multline}
\label{1:03}
g(R,Z|r,z;\epsilon )
=
\frac{
    \left(r^2+R^2+(z-Z)^2+\epsilon ^2\right)
}{
    \sqrt{(r-R)^2+(z-Z)^2+\epsilon ^2}
}
\\
\times
K\left(
    -\frac
        {4 r R}
        {(r-R)^2+(z-Z)^2+\epsilon ^2}
\right)
\\
-
\sqrt{(r-R)^2+(z-Z)^2+\epsilon ^2}
\\
\times
E\left(
    -
    \frac
        {4 r R}
        {(r-R)^2+(z-Z)^2+\epsilon ^2}
\right)
,
\end{multline}
where $K(m)$ and $E(m)$ are the complete elliptic integrals of the first kind. In the limit of zero grain parameter, $\epsilon=0$, this is a magnetic flux at the observation point with coordinates $R$, $Z$, which is created by a coil of radius $r$ located in the $z$ plane and powered by a unit current.

For a given current density distribution $J(r,z)$, the magnetic flux is calculated using the formula
\begin{gather}
\label{1:04}
\psi(R,Z)
=
\frac{1}{2\pi}
\int_{0}^{\infty} dr
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } dz\,
g(R,Z|r,z)\,\left[\frac{4\pi}{c}\right]J(r,z)
\end{gather}
in the CGS system of units. [Factors enclosed in [] revert to $\mu_{0}$ in the SI units and to $1$ in the Heaviside–Lorentz system of units.] Assuming, ignoring theorems of mathematical analysis, that when calculating the derivatives $\psi^{(1,0)}(R,Z)=\frac{\partial}{\partial R}\psi(R,Z)$ and $\psi^{(0,1)}(R ,Z)=\frac{\partial}{\partial Z}\psi(R,Z)$ differentiation operators $\frac{\partial}{\partial Z}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial R}$ can be introduced into the integrand, we can assume that

\begin{gather}
\label{1:04R}
\psi^{(0,1)}(R,Z)
=
\frac{1}{2\pi}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} dr
\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty } dz\,
\left(
    \frac{\partial g}{\partial R}(R,Z|r,z)
\right)
\left[\frac{4\pi}{c}\right]J(r,z)
,
\\
\label{1:04Z}
\psi^{(1,1)}(R,Z)
=
\frac{1}{2\pi}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} dr
\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty } dz\,
\left(
    \frac{\partial g}{\partial Z}(R,Z|r,z)
\right)
\left[\frac{4\pi}{c}\right]J(r,z)
.
\end{gather}
Comparison of the results of applying these formulas with derivatives, which are calculated by the finite difference method, shows that the last two formulas can indeed be used. The derivatives $\frac{\partial g}{\partial R}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial Z}$ are singular at $r=R$, $z=Z$, if $\epsilon =0$, but this singularity is integrable.

However, applying similar approach to computing second derivatives of $\psi$, e.g.,
\begin{gather}
\label{1:04RR}
\psi^{(0,2)}(R,Z)
=
\frac{1}{2\pi}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} dr
\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty } dz\,
\left(
    \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial Z^2}(R,Z|r,z)
\right)
\left[\frac{4\pi}{c}\right]J(r,z)
,
\end{gather}
encounters serious difficulties, since the second derivatives of the Green's function in the limit $\epsilon=0$ have a non-integrable singularity at the point $r=R$, $z=Z$. The integrals can be calculated in Wolfram Mathematica for finite values of $\epsilon$, but the table below shows that the result of numerical integration is not reliable if $\epsilon\leq 10^{-6}$. **We would like to have a reliable result at $\epsilon=0$.**

$$
\begin{array}{l|lccccc}
 timing & \epsilon & -\psi^{(2,0)}/R & \psi^{(1,0)}/R^{2} & -\psi^{(0,2)}/R & \psi^{(1,1)}  \\ \hline
 1.67491 & 0.001 & 2.47355 & 0.0660505 & 3.74359 & -0.0702598 \\
 2.39389 & 0.0001 & 2.47329 & 0.0660654 & 3.74383 & -0.0702724 \\
 3.07955 & 0.00001 & 2.47328 & 0.0660657 & 3.74384 & -0.0702725 \\
 3.8203 & 10^{-6} & 2.47334 & 0.0660657 &
   3.74388 & -0.0702726 \\
 6.16853 & 10^{-7} & 2.4704 & 0.0660657 &
   3.74649 & -0.0702726 \\
 63.8969 & 10^{-8} & 1.24956 & 0.0660657 &
   3.27089 & -0.0702726 \\
 275.57 & 10^{-9} & 2.92302 & 0.0660657 &
   3.16312 & -0.0702726 \\
 439.996 & 0. & 2.97 & 0.0660657 & 3.10416 & -0.493149 \\
 \hline
\end{array}
$$

We see that questions about the integration of singular functions in this forum, as a rule, remain unanswered, but we still hope that someone can suggest a way to achieve this goal. We are looking mainly for some transformation of the right-hand-side of the expression for $\psi^{(0,2)}(R,Z)$ rather then playing with options for Mathematica's `NIntegrate` utility.

Comment: The second derivative of the Green's function is going to have $\delta$-functions in it, which need to be separated out.

Comment: @Buzz: You're right. I tried to subtract $(1/2)\left[-\frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial ^{2}g}{\partial R^{2}}
\frac{1}{R^{2}}\frac{\partial g}{\partial R}
-\frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial ^{2}g}{\partial Z^{2}}
= 2\pi\, \delta(r-R)\,\delta(z-Z) = 2\pi\delta(r-r)\delta(z-Z)\right]$ from $-\frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial ^{2}g}{\partial R^{2}}$, which was supposed to compensate for the delta function, but it didn't help.